# Which wikipedia dump file contains the page actual content?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'd like to extract the actual content from wikipedia [dump file](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/) for a given category however I can't figure out which dump file contains the actual page content.

Answer (score 1):

The files starting with `enwiki-latest-pages-articles<number>.xml...` contain the pages. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download for information about the dump files.

Answer (score 0):

Links to **Wikipedia *dump files***:

- https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dump_torrents#enwiki
- https://dumps.wikimedia.org/